# Entity Framework Contains Query on a varchar column

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have the following Code First entity:

```
public class Department
{ 
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration I have set up makes the following table:

```
dbo.Departments
    DepartmentID INT PRIMARY KEY
    DepartmentName VARCHAR(75)
```

I added an index to DepartmentName manually and run the following query:

```
var depts = new string[] { "Engineering", "Manufacturing" };
var departments = from d in db.Departments
                  where depts.Contains(d.DepartmentName)
                  select d;
```

When I run a trace it produced the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[DepartmentID] AS [DepartmentID], 
[Extent1].[DepartmentName] AS [DepartmentName]
FROM [dbo].[Departments] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[DepartmentName] IN (N'Engineering',N'Manufacturing')
```

Since my column is a varchar and the query is converting the text to NVARCHAR, the optimizer is choosing to do a Clustered Index Scan instead of an Index Seek on my DepartmentName index.

Is there any way to fix this other than changing my database to use nvarchar? Is this a bug or is this normal?

Comment: I don't think that you can change the type of parameter passed into the query from some configuration but you can download EF source code and modify it yourselves to use just `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected if your indexed data table is small.

The minimum amount of data SQL will read from disk is 8k (a page) so if it's using the index then it will need to access the disk twice, once for the index then again for the data. If all the data fits into one 8k data page then it can be read in one go anyway, so using the index would add uneccessary disk IO.